# <br/> tag is not working in firefox but working in chrome

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

[here is the link of my index.html file](https://github.com/rakathegreat71/Dom-tutorial/commit/a99f51708e11d8110dc10e43de48e1af31e63295#diff-eacf331f0ffc35d4b482f1d15a887d3b)

I am using bootstrap 4 beta and HTML. This code is working fine but it has a minor problem. I wanted to add a line space between ul and button tag for which I used `<br>` tag. This `<br>` tag is working fine on chrome but on Firefox browser it is not giving line space.

```
 </ul>
   <br/>
      <button class="btn btn-dark" id="button">
                click me!
            </button>
```

Comment: You are mixing `HTML` and `XHTML` syntax. Try to use `<br>`.

Comment: i have tried it but it is also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove `<br />` tag.Use the below code.

```
<div class="mt-3">
  <button class="btn btn-dark" id="button">
     click me!
  </button>
<div>
```

Comment: thanks it is working. can you tell me why <br> tag is not working. I really want to know.

Comment: Using `<br/>` to add spacing between HTML elements is bad practice. I would always prefer assigning CSS padding or margins to your form elements.Perhaps,adding line breaks should only be used inside paragraphs to indicate a new line.Happy coding.